# @ApiModelProperty example property does not support Map data types

Tags: java, swagger

I have a Rest service like :

```
@POST
@Path("/{myUrl")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response upsertSwitchingInfo(@NotNull ComputingRuleDetailsDto 
                                          computingRuleDetailsDto){
//implementation
 return Response.ok().build();
}
```

ComputingRuleDetailsDto class :

```
public class ComputingRuleDetailsDto {

private String name;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Parameters values",
        example =   "{'parameterName': 'String', 'expirationDate' : 'String'}",
        dataType = "Map[String,String]",
        reference = "Map",
        required = true)
private Map<String,String> parameters;

//getters and setters
}
```

Swagger display only name without parameters map :

```
{
   "name": "string"
}
```

I want to display the both :

```
{
  "name": "String",
  "parameters": {
        "parameterName": "String",
        "expirationDate": "String"
  }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not forget getters & setters for `parameters` attribute? I can only reproduce your issue if I don't create getters & setters for `parameters` otherwise the example is visible.

Comment: @VladimirIlyich yes i'm sure! getters and setters exists for parameters attribute.